# no output in python but output in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, output, jupyter

Running the following codes

```py
with open('abc', 'wt') as fh:
    fh.write('\n'.join(['a','b','c']))
```

in `ipython`, no outputs as expected;
however, in `jupyter` notebook, output like `[Out 4]: 5`.

It's possibly related to

```py
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

in jupyter. But what's the strange thing jupyter output and how to prevent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jupyter, but if it's a REPL that prints the results of expressions as they're evaluated, it's printing the return value of `fh.write`. `write` returns the numbers of characters written, so that's being printed out.

`_ = fh.write` prevents the output because `=` is a statement that does not evaluate to a value. You may also be able to prevent the output by doing something like `fh.write(...); None`. I wouldn't recommend doing this in real code, but for the sake of limiting output, it may be beneficial.